# How many entries in the sequence $x_n$ given by recursion $x_1=1\ ,\ x_{n+1}=p_{x_n}$ are known?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

The sequence $x_n$ with the recursion $x_1=1\ ,\ x_{n+1}=p_{x_n}$ , where
$p_k$ denotes the $k-th$ prime, has the following values :

```
 1            1
 2            2
 3            3
 4            5
 5           11
 6           31
 7          127
 8          709
 9        5 381
10       52 711
11      648 391
12    9 737 333
13  174 440 041
```

- How many values of this sequence are currently known ?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A007097

Comment: This link shows that at least $23$ values are known.